# Memory leak when bulk mailing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, actionmailer, amazon-ses

I'm doing an email delivery in the background (more than 1k letters). The server is on Heroku. For background tasks, I use `sucker_punch`. Rails is 4.1.6, web-server is `passenger`. This is my code:

```
def email_blast message, child_message_id, resend
    @download_url = message.doc_file_size ? message.doc.url : ''
    @subscriber = message.subscriber
    @message = message
    send_message child_message_id, resend
end

def send_message child_message_id, resend
    messages = child_message_id ? Message.where(id: child_message_id) : Message.where(parent_message_id: @message.id)
    messages = messages.joins(:pending_messages).uniq if resend && child_message_id.nil?
    subject = 'New Message'
    type = @message.type.split('::').second || @message.type.split('::').first
    messages.each do |message|
      send_mail message.all_email_addresses, action_name, subject, message, type
    end
end


def send_mail emails, template, subject, model, type
    response = mail(to: emails, subject: subject,
                    template_name: template).deliver!
    create_track_emails response.string.split(' ').third.strip, get_status(response), 'delivered', emails, model, type
  rescue => e
    create_track_emails '00000', 'failed', e.message, emails, model, type
end

def get_status response
    response.status == '250' ? 'success' : 'failed'
end

def create_track_emails smtp_message_id, status, description, emails, model, type
    id = type == 'Logon' ? model.id : model.to_id
    emails.each do |email|
      model.track_emails.create(email_address: email,
                                status: status,
                                status_description: description,
                                smtp_message_id: smtp_message_id,
                                subscriber_id: model.subscriber_id,
                                user_id: id,
                                message_type: type)
    end
end
```

I observe memory leak. I also see that the partial render time increases with each letter:

[image]

Please tell me what can be the problem, and where to dig.

Comment: `model.track_emails.create` will keep appending records to the same array if `model` is re-used between calls. This could lead to significant memory usage since the garbage collector can't release anything retained in there, those records are considered "in use". You can sometimes side-create the emails outside of that association to avoid this.

Comment: @tadman yes, the model is re-used. this model Message. As for emails, there can be a maximum of two email addresses. Could you please tell me, what kind of decision do you propose? Are you sure that the time of rendering and memory leak is related with this?

Comment: @tadman and if I do create track_emails in a callback after_create, will there be a memory leak?

Comment: Ruby doesn't have conventional memory leaks. It has "unintentionally retained" objects.

Comment: @tadman could you please tell me, what kind of solution would you suggest in this case?